# Java matches doesn't match

Tags: java, string

Could someone explain why the following statement in java returns false?

```java
boolean results = "123/#".matches("\\d/#")
```

I tried to escape the forward slash and the pound sign, but this was being marked as redundant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.matches() in Java requires the *full* string to match the regex, as if it was bounded with `^ ... $`. So imagine that you're actually testing the regex `^\d/#$` here.

To allow the string to contain anything else before/after, you must explicitly allow that in the regex using `.*` (anything), for example:

```java
boolean results = "123/#".matches(".*\\d/#.*")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've seen now in the documentation of java that there is a second method called find(regex) to do exactly that, but your solution works fine too!

Answer (score 0):

`\d` matches a single digit, if you want to match 1 or more, add a quantifier `\d+`.

```
boolean results = "123/#".matches("\\d+/#")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually i didn't describe the full requirements of my question right.. I just wanted to find the following pattern inside a string <digit><forwardSlash><poundSign>. I didn't care for whatever else is inside the string (could be more sign, letters, digits, ...). Sorry for the lack of description and thanks for the help!